# What does it mean if console.log(4) outputs undefined in Chrome Console?

Tags: google-chrome, console

I used the Chrome Console to write a simple statement:

```
console.log(4)
```

and received the 
Output:

```
4
```

`undefined`

What does the undefined statement mean?
Does the undefined statement imply correct execution? If I execute the statement via a separate html file and then look at the console, the output is just 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome/Firefox console.log always prepends a line saying undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-prepends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Comment: not sure that this can be a duplicate if it was asked in '12, and the one you linked was asked in '13...

Comment: I believe `Which thread has better and clear-cut answers` is also a criterion while marking a question as duplicate. It is a way of better consolidation of related threads  on SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `undefined` is the return value of `console.log(...)`.

You can see this by defining two functions in the console, one returning something, and the other returning nothing, e.g. like this:

```
function f1() {
  return 1;
}
function f2() {
  return;
}
```

And then calling them separately (manually)

```
f1(); // shows '1'
```

and

```
f2(); // shows 'undefined'
```

Also note the little symbol before these return value string.

Comment: Oh cool. Is this featured implemented as such for debugging purposes?

Comment: interesting: apparently the console gives you the most recent return value, so if you call f2(); f1(); the output is just 1

Comment: By calling them after each other on the same line, you're effectively discarding the first result. By the way, if you just put `var x = f1();`, you'll also see `1`, because the result of that expression is still `1`. Which is why statements like `x = y = z = f1()` work.

Comment: @Bart - For me 'var x = f1();' in the console still gives me undefined. But of course just f1() returns 1 like it should.

Comment: Hmm apparently calling `var x=f1();` gives `undefined` while calling `x=f1()` (i.e. without the `var` keyword) gives `1`. Not sure if this is new behavior since my previous comment or if I simply missed it. Thanks for noting this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it and even with a preset variable it did not work in my Safari:

```
i = 2;
console.log(i);
```

This seems to explain the bug that WebKit (engine of both Chrome and Safari) has:
[Link](http://techblog.appnexus.com/2011/webkit-chrome-safari-console-log-bug/)