# Access javascript objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a javascript object which I want to access by a dynamic variable:

```
var color = {
                red : '#ff0000',
                black : '#000000',
                silver : '#7d8989'
            };

var currentColor = $(val).html();

console.log(color[currentColor]);
```

But I get undefined message by the console. How can I access the data?

**EDIT:**

Problem was that the option value had whitespace at its end, thanks everyone for fast reply:

```
var currentColor = $.trim($(val).html());
```

Comment: what is `$(val).html();`

Comment: Did you check what the value for `currentColor` is before you get the value from the `color`-object. If you specify an existing property name, this should work.

Comment: This should work if val.html is "red" etc

Comment: Maybe you want to select an Element with the id "val" if so -> `$("#val").text()`

Comment: Works if i write `var currentColor = "red"` --> http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/LWteu/

Comment: @MohammadAdil this is a string that comes from an option select

@Kenneth yes the value is ok and I also tried to convert this with `String(currentColor` and `currentColor.toString()` without success

Comment: To get the value of a select you want `.val()` not `.html()`!

Comment: @danny . You should have posted your html to make it more clear.

Comment: Is it happening in Chrome console?

Answer (score 2):

This works. Like the comment, I'm not sure what "val" is, but if it's an ID, make sure it's targeted correctly.

HTML:

```
<p id="val">red</p>
```

JS:

```
var color = {
                red : '#ff0000',
                black : '#000000',
                silver : '#7d8989'
            };
var currentColor = $("#val").html();
console.log(color[currentColor]);
```

Comment: @blachawk Dot notation isn't possible with a dynamic value. There is no `currentColor` property of `color` - you have to use bracket notation like they have it

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to trim your string before finding the color in your map:

```
var color = {
    red : '#ff0000',
    black : '#000000',
    silver : '#7d8989'
};

var currentColor = $.trim( $(val).html() );

console.log(color[currentColor]);
```

And it's not very fast to route your data through the DOMNodes like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine, so it is probably something wrong with your selector
See http://jsfiddle.net/9GPbv/1/ works fine

```
<div class="val">red</div>

var color = {
                red : '#ff0000',
                black : '#000000',
                silver : '#7d8989'
            };

var currentColor = $(".val").html();

alert(color[currentColor]);
```

Also if your using an input like at http://jsfiddle.net/tMFZr/ you should use .val() not .html()

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotes in your object since you will be using it as string values:
HTML

```
<div id="val">red</div>
```

JS

```
var color = {
                'red' : '#ff0000',
                'black' : '#000000',
                'silver' : '#7d8989'
            };

var currentColor = $(val).html();

console.log(color[currentColor]);
```

Comment: But then please use `var val = "#val"`

Comment: Sure, but [it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572) stays a bad practise inherited from faulty IE

Comment: in my opinion, not to use var is a bad practice, having your IDs as references to elements is another subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the undefined in the chrome console. IF so please take a look at [What does it mean if console.log(4) outputs undefined in Chrome Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108953/what-does-it-mean-if-console-log4-outputs-undefined-in-chrome-console)

Answer (score 0):

If your html have an id:

```
var color = {
    red : '#ff0000',
    black : '#000000',
    silver : '#7d8989'
};
var currentColor = document.getElementById("val").innerText;
console.log(currentColor);
console.log(color[currentColor]);
```