# "for..in" in Javascript yields "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, undefined, for-in-loop

I'm working on an extension for Chrome and I'm just wondering about the usage of "for..in" in Javascript. Let me explain the issue I've found with an example:

Suppose I have a volatile object of the type `{prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar", ...}`.
I want to save this object in a string in a some syntax, e.g., `"prop1=foo;prop2=bar;..."`. Here is the code I used:

```
var fun = function(data) {
  var str = "";
  for (var i in data) {
    str += i + "=" + data[i] + ";";
  }
  return str;
};
log(fun({x:1, y:2}));
```

That `fun` returns the following string: `undefinedx=1;y=2;`.

I can't really see why it follows this behavior. I know I can use JSON to "stringify" something like this, but actually I just want to understand why it happens.

Comment: Except for two syntax errors(typos, I guess) the code is working to me.

Comment: @LightStyle Three if you count the missing `;` at the end of `fun`'s initialization, but semicolon insertion masks that one. ;)

Comment: Well that's not exactly a thrown syntax error :P

Comment: Correct.  I consider it an error, the same way I consider accidental or sloppy global variable use an error.  (But of course the parser does not.)

Comment: consider using JSON.stringify() instead of hand-packing objects into strings for later use...

Comment: @LightStyle check my comment in the first answer.

Answer (score 5):

Is that the exact code you're running? The missing `+` before `data[i]` leads me to believe it's not. It looks a lot like `str` is starting off uninitialized, as in:

```
var fun = function(data) {
  var str;
  for (var i in data) {
    str += i + "=" + data[i] + ";";
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly this, I just fixed typos in the original question. Sorry. Anyway, the code is not working for me, I keep getting the "undefined" in the string.

Edit: a simpler code who raises the same behavior is the following: `var a = {x:1, y:2}; for(var i in a) { console.log(a[i]); }` and it logs 1, 2 and then returns (?) undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108953/what-does-it-mean-if-console-log4-outputs-undefined-in-chrome-console <-- assuming you're using Chrome, this is the problem(I think it's the same in Firefox and other browsers)

Comment: @LightStyle oh well, thank you! I thought it was a strange behavior from the `for..in` loop.

Comment: No, don't worry, it is confirmed by this simple example: `function foo() {return "foo";}`. In console, type `foo()` --> "foo", type `console.log(foo())` --> "foo" and then, new line and undefined.
@JohnKugelman I was referring to the last problem Finalfire caught, your answer is right ;)

Comment: @LightStyle Ah I follow now. Comment deleted :)