# Chrome dev console outputting undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Every time i see some javascript code on a website, I feel like typing and trying it out on the Chrome's developer's tool console instead of creating a javascript file and then opening it separately in the browser.

Like today, I was viewing Doug Crockford's Js lecture and kept simultaneously running test on whatever he was saying to cross check that feature.

A strange thing that I noticed in the javascript console is that it always outputs the value undefined as a result of any statement that I execute that does not produce a fixed value as below:

> var x = 12;
>   Console o/p < undefined
>
> 2+3
>   Console o/p < 5
>
> +"46"
>   < 46

What does the undefined value mean which Chrome dev console after every declaration.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14633968/465053) question.

Answer (score 0):

If you type it without "var", just

```
x = 12;
```

it will output 12;
but in any case, this is a duplicate question of: 
[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-prepends-a-line-saying-undefined) 
and 
[What does it mean if console.log(4) outputs undefined in Chrome Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108953/what-does-it-mean-if-console-log4-outputs-undefined-in-chrome-console)