# Readig a nested object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var body = {
  "LocationInfo": {
    "Stores": [
      {
        "Number": 524,
        "Name": "Store"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

But I can't read anything inside the object, for example:

`console.log(body["LocationInfo"]["Stores"][0]);` is `undefined`

This is so basic... I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: It works on my console. `Object {Number: 524, Name: "Store"}` is logged.

Comment: Same here. ```var x = body["LocationInfo"]["Stores"][0];```. x is not undefined for me

Comment: You will have to show more of your code. The code you've posted works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/3d7ou2hy/

Comment: it is working for me

Comment: @Juhana this is the full JSON i'm trying to read: http://pastebin.com/1T8HZ5SJ

Comment: That object doesn't have a `LocationInfo` member. https://jsfiddle.net/3d7ou2hy/1/

Comment: @Juhana it's this property `PersonalLocationInfo` i just shortened it

Comment: Then it works equally well. https://jsfiddle.net/3d7ou2hy/2/ Seriously, you have to show a **complete** example that **replicates** the problem – edit the jsfiddle so that it matches the problem you're describing. It's impossible to help if you don't show enough code.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* work as expected; undefined is just the return value of `console.log`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109316/1760344

Comment: Why is this downvoted? 

`console.log("digitalsteez")
VM332:2 digitalsteez
undefined`

This is the same thing that occurs when you run jrbaldwinn's code in the console: 

`console.log(body["LocationInfo"]["Stores"][0]);
VM343:2 Object {Number: 524, Name: "Store"}
undefined`

There's even a symbol that implies that it is the function's return value.

Comment: If you are indeed running this on Node, I'm not sure what's going on. This is what I get with your code on Node: `$ node test.js
{ Number: 524, Name: 'Store' }`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your object. The reason you see that "undefined" is not because your object is wrong or something in it is undefined. Its just that the console appends undefined after console.log(); function is called.
For more knowledge, refer this:

[Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my issue: there's a bug in the node request module that wraps double escapes, so I did:

```
body = JSON.parse(body);
body = JSON.parse(body);
```

twice in a row and it worked!